# how to use delegate method for forms in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am developing a webapp, where i need to have delegate function or like same thing on forms.

I will explain in detail. First of all my webpage contains a select form .

On submitting the form I prevented the redirect by using jQuery `preventDefault` function. And the results are also displayed in the same page.

The result returned is also made into form. I want this form also to get result on the same page using jQuery.

Is it possible?

```
<form id="svs" method="post" action="someurl.php">
    <select name='Subject'>
    <option value=ANATOMY>ANATOMY</option>
    <option value=Surgery>Surgery</option>
    <option value=PHYSIOLOGY>PHYSIOLOGY</option>
    <option value=PHYSIOLOGY-RESP>PHYSIOLOGY-RESP</option>
    <option value=CIVIL>CIVIL</option>  
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Select">
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

my jquery file is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

 $('#sqb_edit').submit(function(){
  return false;
    });

 $('#submit').click(function(){
 $.post( 
   $('#sqb_edit').attr('action'),
   $('#sqb_edit :input').serializeArray(),
function(result){
   $('#result').html(result);
  });
  });
```

someurl.php code is

```
  <?php
  $subject = $_POST['Subject'];

  if($subject==ANATOMY){
   ?>
  <form id="edit" method="post" action="someotherurl.php">
   <select id="Q" name="q">
   <option value="blah..blah">blah..blahh</option>
   <option value="blah..blah">blah..blahh</option>
   <option value="blah..blah">blah..blahh</option>
  </select>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button button-    primary" value="Select">
 </form>
 <div id="result"></div>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
```

My query is to select this form again in the same page without redirecting to someotherurl.php by using jQuery.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am understanding your question correctly, I take it you want to display the results of the submission on the same page, without redirecting. If so, try using AJAX.

Here's a nice example: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form

Comment: If there are two forms on the same page and using ajax to submit form. If i tried to submit the first form it works normally. But ajax not working for second form. @Lightwind